# Javascript- Uppercase letters to lower case and vise versa

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement

I am interested in making any uppercase letters lowercase and any lowercase letters uppercase.
If I have code like the below code, what should I put in the blank spaces of this if/else statement: `if (string[i] == )` and the `else if (string [i] == )`. Here is the rest of my code:

```
      var sentence = "Whats Up! MAKE ME uppercase or LOWERCASE";

      var theString = sentence.split("")

      for (var i = theString.length; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (theString[i] == ) {

          theString[i].toLowerCase();

        }

        else if (theString [i] == ) {

          theString[i].toUpperCase();

        }

      }

      var connectedSentence = theString.join("");

      console.log(connectedSentence);
```

Have I made any other mistakes? The expected output is make me UPPERCASE OR lowercase.

Comment: You're supposed to make your assignments/tests yourself.

Comment: `if (theString[i].toLowerCase() === theString[i])` should be ok

Comment: Note that you're starting your for loop at a value 1 to high. should be `var i = theString.length - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (theString[i] == theString[i].toUpperCase()) {

    theString[i]=  theString[i].toLowerCase();

    }

    else if (theString[i] == theString[i].toLowerCase()) {

    theString[i]=  theString[i].toUpperCase();

    }
```

Comment: Because it does not do anything.

Comment: Correct, but the question was, "what should I put in the blank spaces". theString[i] = theString[i].toUpperCase() should be inside the if. But that was not the question.

Comment: Correct, and my statement is still correct as well: the code you posted in your answer makes no sense.

Comment: Voila, I changed my edit to a more useful code snippet.

Comment: For some reason it is coming up with an error which says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined"

Comment: @rdood2 see DrunkWolf comment on your post

Answer (score 6):

You can use split, map and join to work fast on strings in javascript.

```
var sentence = "Whats Up! MAKE ME uppercase or LOWERCASE"
var inversed = sentence.split('').map(function(c) {
    return c.toLowerCase() == c ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowerCase();
}).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply test with `RegExp`;

```js
var flipCase = function(str) {
  var arr = str.split('');
  var c, rgx = /[a-z]/;
  str = '';
  while (arr.length) {
    c = arr.shift();
    str += rgx.test(c) ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowerCase();
  }
  return str;
};

alert(flipCase("Hello World !"));
```